# matplotlib.pyplot non numeric barplot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have 2 questions

First
is there a way to barplot(unstacked) this data frame as I am getting "Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'midterm':['A','B','B','D'],'Final':['C','A','D','B']}, index=['math', 'sport', 'History', 'Physics'])
```

Second question:
I manually plot the data of the dataframe like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.DataFrame({'midterm':['A','B','B'],'Final':['C','A','D']}, index=['math', 'sport', 'History'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.asarray([1,10])
width=0.5
plt.bar(index, df.iloc[0,:], width,label='Math')
plt.bar(index+width, df.iloc[1,:], width, label='Sport')
plt.bar(index+2*width, df.iloc[2,:], width, label='History')
xticks=['midterm','final']
plt.xticks=(index,xticks)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[What the code produces is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDtbJ.png)

This has two problems,
- first , A, B, C, D are not ordered
- second, the y axis starts at point 0,0 which makes the bar of grade C in this graph not visible at all

[what i aim to do is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dysud.jpg)

Comment: Does the below answer addresses your problem?

Comment: yep, that was really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your second question. You should restrict your question to a single query. I would map the grades onto integers and then later set the y-ticks. To do so, I define a mapping dictionary and a function `mapping` which takes the alphabetical grades and converts them into integer values for bar plot height.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'midterm':['A','B','B'],'Final':['C','A','D']}, index=['math', 'sport', 'History'])
map_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D':4}

def mapping(keys):    
    values = [map_dict[i] for i in keys]
    return values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.asarray([1,10])
width=0.5
plt.bar(index, mapping(df.iloc[0,:]), width,label='Math')
plt.bar(index+width, mapping(df.iloc[1,:]), width, label='Sport')
plt.bar(index-width, mapping(df.iloc[2,:]), width, label='History')
xticks=['midterm','final']
ax.set_yticks(range(1, 5))
ax.set_yticklabels(map_dict.keys())
plt.legend()
```

[image]